# How to create a background process of Phoenix Shell in Cent OS?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, pipeline

so I know about creating named pipes using makefifo.
I use this:-

```
makefifo yourfifo
python sqlline.py < yourfifo &
cat "a.sql" > yourfifo
```

The problem is I have to do fg once, for the process to actually run. How can I truly make it run in background??

Comment: Why are you involving a FIFO at all? What's wrong with just ”python sqlline.py < a.sql &”?

Comment: I have to exit sqlline.py again and again and enter different sql files into it. I thought it would be better to keep it in the background and run sql files that way. Also, with your solution too I have to put fg again.